# External JS files in Yii

Tags: javascript, yii

I'm trying to call an external JS file from my Yii asset folder and the source code is showing the right file, but the JS is not responding.

I included this in my view file ...

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile( Yii::app()->request->baseurl . '/assets/test.js' ); ?>
```

And I know this is the problem b/c when I replicated it in a *non-Yii* folder it worked, and when I sourced the online JS file *in Yii* it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The assets folder should be only used to publish there files by the [asset manager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager). For example if the JS file is part of a widget, you can place it in protected/components/widgets/assets/yourJsFile.js and use the assets manager to publish it automatically in the /assets folder. Read more here: [Understanding Assets](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/). You probably would want to put your file in /js/test.js and work directly with it, if not using the asset manager.

I still do not know if this is the issue, if the file is loading. If this doesn't help, please show some more code - where and how do you load that js file in the views, what is in the file, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[CClientScript::registerScriptFile()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScriptFile-detail) can put the <script> tag in various parts of your page's HTML (three places to be exact: in the <head> or at the start or end of the <body>).  Sometimes the position matters because the order of script tags matters.  I found ordering to matter when I used jQuery UI.

By default it puts the script tag in the <head>. If you play with the position you may find it working.

The little bit of code you show doesn't indicate any problems.  But you may want to give a bigger example and/or show what you did that worked.  By the way, in Yii you should not be putting things directly into the assets folder.  Items get in here by being published through the asset manager.